# Scala: `with` after class body

Tags: scala, traits, mixins

One usually mixins trait this way:

```
trait Parent {
  def f: Int = -1
}

class Child extends Parent {
  override val f: Int = 1
}
```

Though, I accidentally found, that if we only use constants inside class body, we are able to achieve the same one more way:

```
class ChildBodyBefore extends {
  override val f: Int = 1
} with Parent
```

Seems like these Child and ChildBodyBefore definitions works the same way:

```
new Child().f // 1
new ChildBodyBefore().f // 1
```

Why does second form even exist then? Do some particular reasons to use that `extends { ... }` syntax exist?